# Flask on WAMP only seeing directory listings

Tags: python, flask, wamp, wampserver, wsgi

I am trying to publish a test python flask application to WAMP. I have gone through many tutorials, but face the issue of only seeing directory listings when I navigate to the app. I believe the wsgi module is setup correctly as the apache logs flag that the module has loaded, and as you can see from the screenshot below the server text also suggests the same. Has anyone else came across this, and resolved.

[image]

Here is my wsgi file:

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/wamp64/www/flaskapp') 

from webtool import app as application
```

Here is my **init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__ name__) 

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World"

if __ name__ == '__ main__':
    app.run()
```

The additional lines added to my httpd.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "d:/program files/anaconda3/lib/site-
packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp35-win_amd64.pyd"

LoadFile "d:/program files/anaconda3/python35.dll"
WSGIPythonHome "d:/program files/anaconda3"
```

Virtualhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName flaskapp
        WSGIScriptAlias /flaskapp c:/wamp64/www/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
        DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/flaskapp
        <Directory c:/wamp64/www/flaskapp>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be my virtual hosts file. I cannot have two references to the same location (*:80) in the one file.

Updated file below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /flaskapp c:/wamp64/www/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
    <Directory c:/wamp64/www/flaskapp>
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```